# JScrollPane overlapping in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtable, jscrollpane

I can't figure out way, when i run my program on a different computer, the 3 JScrollPane placed in a vertical order (North,Center,South) insider a JFrame, overlap each other making the tables unreadable
Here's the code for 1 of 3 JscrollPane.

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    frame.setVisible(true);


    DefaultTableModel mod1 = new DefaultTableModel(col,0) {
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row,int column) {
            if(column==0 || column==1 || column==2 || column==3 || column==4 || column==5) {
                return false;
            }else {
                return true;
            }
        }
    };  
    JTable giorno1 = new JTable(mod1);
    giorno1.setFont(new Font("Arial",0,15));
    giorno1.setRowHeight(20);
    giorno1.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
    JScrollPane scroll1= new JScrollPane(giorno1);
    scroll1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(),
            "Giorno1",TitledBorder.CENTER,
            TitledBorder.TOP));
```

And the part when i put allo of them i a JFrame

```
    frame.add(scroll1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.add(scroll2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.add(scroll3, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frame.validate();
```

any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. We can't tell the context of how you use the few random lines of posted code.

Answer (score 0):

Don´t add the ScrollPanes directly to the JFrame.

First you need to set the LayoutManager (in your case BorderLayout) to the Container of the JFrame. Then you can add the ScrollPanes to that Container.

It would be a bit more fancier if you create a Background JPanel and add that to the container. That should look somewhat like this here:

```
JPanel backgroundPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
backgroundPane.add(scrollPane1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
frame.getContentPane().add(backgroundPane);
```

Edit: I also noticed that you use frame.setVisible(true) before you add the panels. Use this method after you add the panels, because that could have been causing the issue as well.

Comment: The default layout manager of the content pane of a JFrame is a BorderLayout .

Comment: Ah, yes true. Thanks for pointing that out! Won´t make a difference in my example though.